# Ansible skip remaining tasks in playbook on condition

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am new to Ansible and have to update existing playbook tasks. Initially, there are 2 tasks to copy yml variable values to files - this runs in a loop per each cert and keys values.
I want if the copy tasks are not changed - basically if the content is same the files are not overwritten, then the remaining tasks in the playbook should not be executed.

```
    - name: Copy cert files
      copy:
        content: "{{item.value}}"
        dest: /home/copyTest/dest/{{item.key}}.crt
        owner: test
        group: test
        mode: 0644
      with_dict: '{{certs_dict}}'
    - name: Copy key files
      copy:
        content: "{{item.value}}"
        dest: /home/copyTest/dest/{{item.key}}.key
        owner: test
        group: test
        mode: 0644
      with_dict: "{{keys_dict}}"
    - name: Stop server
        ...
        ...
```

If both these copy tasks results are unchanged, i.e, none of certs and keys files are unchanged, then the further tasks(Stop server, Start server, etc.) should not be executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I exit Ansible playbook without error on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451793/how-do-i-exit-ansible-playbook-without-error-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `register` keyword to store the results of your first two tasks:

```
- name: Copy cert files
  copy:
    content: "{{item.value}}"
    dest: /home/copyTest/dest/{{item.key}}.crt
    owner: test
    group: test
    mode: 0644
  with_dict: '{{certs_dict}}'
  register: cert_results

- name: Copy key files
  copy:
    content: "{{item.value}}"
    dest: /home/copyTest/dest/{{item.key}}.key
    owner: test
    group: test
    mode: 0644
  with_dict: "{{keys_dict}}"
  register: key_results
```

Place you remaining tasks in a separate task list file, and then in your main playbook conditionally include those additional tasks only if there were changes:

```
- include_tasks: additional_tasks.yml
  when: cert_results is changed or key_results is changed
```

You can read about including tasks [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html).

You can achieve something similar using a `block` in your playbook:

```
- when: cert_results is changed or key_results is changed
  block:
    - name: Stop server

    - name: Do something else

    ...
```

You can read about blocks [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html).

Comment: Thank you @larsks works perfect. I went with the block: approach and it works perfectly. Thanks again for such a quick answer