# Ansible: How do I run an entire playbook based on a condition?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements

**Context:** provisioning fresh new servers.

I would like to provision them just once especially the update part.
After launching the first playbook bootstrap.yml I made it leave a file in a folder for me to know that the playbook ran well.

So then in the same playbook I would have to add a condition above every task (which I did) to check for the existance of this file.
If file exists skip running the playbook against all those machines who have that file.

**Problem:** How do I add the condition to run the playbook only if the file isn't found? I don't want to add a "when:" statement for each of my own tasks I find it silly.

**Question:** Does anyone have a better solution that maybe solves this with a single line or a parameter in the inventory file that I haven't thought of?

edit:

This is how i check for the file

```
- name: Bootstrap check
    find:
      path: /home/bot/bootstrapped-ok
    register: bootstrap
```

and then when condition would be:

```
when: bootstrap.matched == 0
```

so if file is not found run the entire playbook.

Comment: Condition on a role, import_role, include_role, block, etc., Pre checks in `pre_tasks` using `end_host`, `end_play`.... there are many possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be over-complicating this slightly. Would it be accurate to say "I want to bail early on a playbook without error under a certain condition?"

If so, you want "end_host"

[How do I exit Ansible play without error on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451793/how-do-i-exit-ansible-play-without-error-on-a-condition)

Just begin with a check for the file, and end_host if it's found.

```
  - name: Bootstrap check
    stat:
      path: /home/bot/bootstrapped-ok
    register: bootstrap

  - name: End the play if previous provisioning was successful
    meta: end_host
    when: bootstrap.stat.exists == True

  - name: Confinue if bootstrap missing
    debug:
      msg: "Hello"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my issue! 
I was definitely over complicating it. But also wasn't aware of meta: end_host existance.

Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. It is a very forest for the trees kind of problem, easy to go down the wrong path. Please do up vote/mark this answer as accepted if it fixed you up, helps me out.

Comment: I did Matt, but it tells me that I'm too new of an user and will need 15 reputation points before the upvote actually goes public..

Comment: Oh of course. Welcome to Stack Overflow.